# Csharp WebBrowser Navigate Give Script Error

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control

I want to call website URL in .exe.
  I will share this .exe or program with my website user so instead of website they will use program

So in windows application I give WebBrowser Navigate but it give script error

What is problem with this code?

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate("http://okey101.xyz/index.html");
```

It give that error 
[image]

is webbrowser user internet explorer background?If yes can we change it?

Comment: Yes, the WebBrowser control uses IE and no, you can't change it. Your alternative would be something like this: https://cefsharp.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this line in your constructor:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Note that with this line you just "ignore" these errors and prevent them to be shown to the user. It's still very useful because most of the script errors arent supposed to be "errors" per se.